# @Scheduled Spring

Tags: spring

Как сделать так, чтобы выполнялась фоновая процедура?

ApplicationContext.xml:

```
 <!-- Тест класс -->
<bean id="plannedVacationServiceCronTrigger"
        class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerBean">
    <property name="jobDetail" ref="ru..путь к классу...SchedulerTest" /> 
    <property name="cronExpression" value="${cmj.quartz.SchedulerTest.trigger}" />
</bean>
```

Класс, в котором находится процедура:

```
package ...;

import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Scheduled;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableScheduling;

@EnableScheduling
public class SchedulerTest {

@Scheduled(fixedDelay = 5000)
public void testmethod() throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Вызов фоновой процедуры");
    }

}
```

Файл schedules.properties:

```
cmj.quartz.SchedulerTest.suspend=false
cmj.quartz.SchedulerTest.trigger=0 0/2 * * * ?
```

При запуске приложения сначала всё деплоится нормально, затем падает

```
at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.generateKey(CacheAspectSupport.java:482)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.findCachedItem(CacheAspectSupport.java:431)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.execute(CacheAspectSupport.java:333)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.execute(CacheAspectSupport.java:299)
    at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheInterceptor.invoke(CacheInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy188.findPersonByLogin(Unknown Source)
    at ru.intertrust.cm.core.dao.impl.access.UserGroupGlobalCacheImpl.getUserIdByLogin(UserGroupGlobalCacheImpl.java:43)
    at ru.intertrust.cm.core.dao.impl.access.AccessControlServiceImpl.getUserIdByLogin(AccessControlServiceImpl.java:295)
    at ru.intertrust.cm.core.dao.impl.access.AccessControlServiceImpl.createCollectionAccessToken(AccessControlServiceImpl.java:305)
    at ru.intertrust.cm.core.business.impl.CrudServiceBaseImpl.findAndLockByUniqueKey(CrudServiceBaseImpl.java:412)
    at ru.intertrust.cm.core.business.impl.CrudServiceImpl.findAndLockByUniqueKey(CrudServiceImpl.java:438)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.java:52)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:437)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.delegateInterception(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:70)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.doMethodInterception(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:80)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.processInvocation(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:93)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:63)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.invocationmetrics.ExecutionTimeInterceptor.processInvocation(ExecutionTimeInterceptor.java:43)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
```

Фоновая процедура, естесственно, не запускается. Не подскажете в чём может быть дело?

Comment: Судя по твоему описанию, указанный стэктрейс не имеет никакого отношения к тому, почему у тебя не запускается таймер. Обрати внимание на то, что происходит в твоём классе `ru.intertrust.cm.core.dao.impl.access.UserGroupGlobalCacheImpl`

Comment: Во-вторых, `@EnableScheduling` надо вешать на класс с аннотацией  `@Configuration`. А твой `SchedulerTest` надо пометить как `@Component`, в случае если ты используешь аннотации